# How do you wrap a link around the block header text with Drupal?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

(sorry if i'm redundant) What's the easiest way to wrap a link to the header of any block title text?

I know a workaround would be to just not include a title and add it in the content; but that's not the most convenient at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I f I understand that your question is *How to make block title a link?* You can use this module http://drupal.org/project/block_titlelink